# Select all text before <br>

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following awful HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="102036.pdf">102036</a> - <em>In re</em> State v. Williams <a href="#">video</a><br>
    <a href="104236.pdf">104236</a> - University of Kansas Hosp. Auth. v. Board of Wabaunsee County Comm'rs <a href="#">video</a>
</p>
```

I want to use XPath to capture all of the text following each `</a>`, so:

```
Item 1: " - In re State v. Williams
Item 2: " - University of Kansas Hosp. Auth. v. Board of Wabunsee County
```

Alternatively, I could just capture all text, and that would be fine too:

```
Item 1: "102036 - In re State v. Williams
Item 2: "104236 - University of Kansas Hosp. Auth. v. Board of Wabunsee County
```

I've been trying various things for a while now, but making no progress. I want something like:

```
/a/following::text()[before::br]
```

Help?

Comment: trought with **jquery** ?

Comment: @MaurizioBattaghini, this isn't browser-side, I need to do it with xpath and lxml. Alas, Jquery isn't a tool in my kit.

Comment: my fault, sorry i can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I've found so far is to simply nuke the errant `<em>` nodes.

So:

```
elem = html.xpath('//p')[0]
etree.strip_tags(elem, 'em')
```

Then, using the cleaner html, a simple XPath can be used:

```
texts = [e.tail for e in elem.xpath('//a')]
```

Credit where due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788559/64911

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, pal:

```
//a//following-sibling::text() | //a//following-sibling::*[not(self::a)]/text()
```

Comment: Hm, this is close, but had three results. See my answer for the fix I'm using.

Answer (score -2):

If you have firebug installed and are running Firefox, for this and all future xpath needs you can just follow this tutorial:

http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug

Very easy way to find the xpath for anything on a page.

Comment: But this would probably not be flexible enough and it will be necessary to chain many XPath expressions together.